# How to use Split function in stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, split

I am selecting the values like below:

```
select browser, firstname, lastname from details
```

Here the browser value will be like this:

```
33243@Firefox@dsfsd
34234@google@dfsd
```

And separately I have used split function for single value as below:

```
select * from dbo.split('33243@Firefox@dsfsd','@')
```

Result is:

```
items
===========
33243
firefox
dsfsd
```

So I have used split function like below

```
select split(browser, '@'), firstname, lastname from details
```

but its not working...

What I need is

33243@Firefox@dsfsd

instead of displaying the value like this into the grid,
have to display only Firefox into the grid.

Comment: Not sure what the ultimate result you want it, but try

select firstname, lastname, a.* from details, dbo.split('33243@Firefox@dsfsd','@') a

and you should get three rows of data with the same first and last name along with each element.

Comment: @jim O'NEil : My Ultimate result should be the word between '@' symbol.
 I have written spearate split function also. Its splitting when I pass the single value like this '33243@Firefox@dsfsd'.
But I need to split many values in one column in a table. I dont know how call split function in storedprocedure

Answer (score 1):

Since you know you want the second element each time, you could write a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitElement] 
(
    @inputString nvarchar(2000),    --The input string
    @elem   int,    --The 1-based element index to return,
    @delimiter nvarchar(1)  --The delimiter char
)
RETURNS nvarchar(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(2000)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @result = value
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER By Position) as rownum FROM dbo.split(@inputString,@delimiter)
    ) as t
    WHERE rownum=@elem

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @result

END

GO
```

Then you can call:

```
select [dbo].[fn_SplitElement](browser,2,'@') as 'BrowserName', firstname, lastname from details
```

Comment: in above function. position and value is column name?

Comment: @Sham Yes, that was a left-over from my implementaion of split. You could replace both with 'items' for your definition.

Answer (score 0):

You do not state which version of SQL Server you are using or which split function. However, most split functions return a table rather than rows so you'll need to use a JOIN to join the two tables (the first is the split, the second is the rest of the fields).

For more information in SQL split functions, see Erland Sommarskog's page at http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html .

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a Split function and that will be use when you want.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(   
    @List nvarchar(max),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(1)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table (
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Value nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
    Begin 
        Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
        Select 
            Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
        Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
    End 

    Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
    Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

    Return
END
```

after that you can call the function in your query as below.

```
SELECT * FROM anotherTable WHERE user_id IN(dbo.split(@user_list,','))
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have used below query instead of using split function.. its working perfectly..

```
 select 
        SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(browser, CHARINDEX ('@', browser)+1,LEN(browser)-charindex('@', browser)),
        0,
        CHARINDEX('@',SUBSTRING(browser, CHARINDEX ('@', browser)+1,LEN(browser)-CHARINDEX('@', browser)))),
    firstname, lastname from details
```